# How can i stop the php from showing the book twice if it has more than one author

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

PHP

```
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT bk.title AS Title, bk.year AS Year, bk.publisher AS Publisher, aut.authorname AS Author 
         FROM book bk 

         JOIN book_category bk_cat 
         ON bk_cat.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN categories cat 
         ON cat.id = bk_cat.category_id

         JOIN books_authors bk_aut 
         ON bk_aut.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN authors aut
         ON aut.id = bk_aut.author_id";

if (isset($_GET['searchInput'])){

    $getters = array();
    $queries = array();

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
        if (!empty($temp)){
        if (!in_array($key, $getters)){
            $getters[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($getters)) {

        foreach($getters as $key => $value){
            ${$key} = $value;
            switch ($key) {
                case 'searchInput':
                    array_push($queries,"(bk.title LIKE '%$searchInput%' 
                    || bk.description LIKE '%$searchInput%' || bk.isbn LIKE '%$searchInput%' 
                    || bk.keywords LIKE '%$searchInput%' || aut.authorname LIKE '%$searchInput%')");
                break;
                case 'srch_publisher':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk.publisher = $srch_publisher)");
                break;
                case 'srch_author':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk_aut.author_id = $srch_author)");
                break;          
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($queries)){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        if($i < count($queries)){
            $sql .= $query." AND ";
        } else {
            $sql .= $query;
        }   
        $i++;
    }
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY bk.title ASC";

}
```

HTML

```
<?php if($tot_rows > 0) { ?>
            <table id="tbl_repeat">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="bookTitle">Book Title</th>
                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                    <th scope="col">Publisher</th>
                </tr>
                <?php do{ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bookTitle"><a href=""><?php echo $rows['Title']; ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['Author']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['Publisher']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)); ?>
            </table>
            <?php } 
            else {
                if (!empty($queries)){
                    echo "<p>There are no records matching your search criteria.</p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>There are currently no records available.</p>";
                }
            }
            ?>
    </div>
```

[image]

As you can see from the image it shows the book twice with two authors, as you know books can have many authors so i am trying to figure out how it would just show one or the first one it finds related to that book.

Comment: [`You already asked the same question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22428143/) (*correct me if I'm wrong*)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah i am really at a loss here :( sorry

Comment: You were given [`an answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22430555/) have you not tried it? Someone upvoted the answer, so there must be something about it that will solve your problem or lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah ofcourse i tried it didnt change the results

Comment: You should have made a comment to the person who gave you the answer then. No sense in "not" saying anything. How is that person to know whether it worked or not? You need to interact ;-)

Comment: I see that you've finally gotten the answer you were looking for, *great.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be achieved using GROUP_CONCAT. Check out [this](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) tutorial to get your head around it. EDIT, [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/) might be a better explantaion.

So I guess it would be:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT bk.title AS Title, bk.year AS Year, bk.publisher AS Publisher, GROUP_CONCAT(aut.authorname) AS Author 
         FROM book bk 

         JOIN book_category bk_cat 
         ON bk_cat.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN categories cat 
         ON cat.id = bk_cat.category_id

         JOIN books_authors bk_aut 
         ON bk_aut.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN authors aut
         ON aut.id = bk_aut.author_id
GROUP BY bk.title, bk.year, bk.pulisher
```

Comment: `Another Happy Ending` then.